# Does this integral have a closed form? $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{e^{ikx} dx}{1-\mu e^{-x^2}}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

The original integral contains $\sin [n(x+a)] \sin [l(x+a)]$ but I think this form is simpler:

$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{e^{ikx} dx}{1-\mu e^{-x^2}}$$

$\mu <1$, so I can use the Taylor expansion to calculate the integral with very good accuracy.

$$\frac{1}{1-\mu e^{-x^2}}=1+\sum^{\infty}_{j=1} \mu^j e^{-jx^2}$$

And then of course I complete the square in the exponent and it becomes Poisson integral.

The series will be:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}\frac{ \mu^j}{\sqrt{j}} e^{-b^2/j}$$

($b$ depends on $k$, but in the original expression it is more complex, so its exact form doesn't matter, it's sufficient that it is real. )

If this series or the original integral have a closed form it will be more convenient. I wasn't able to find it in the literature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{ikx}}{1-\mu e^{-x^2}}\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(kx)}{1-\mu e^{-x^2}}\,dx &=& 2\sum_{r=1}^{+\infty}\mu^r\int_{0}^{+\infty}\cos(kx)e^{-rx^2}\,dx\\&=&2\sum_{r\geq 1}\mu^r \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{r}}\,e^{-\frac{k^2}{4r}}\\&=&2\sqrt{\pi}\sum_{r\geq 1}\frac{\mu^r}{\sqrt{r}}\,e^{-\frac{k^2}{4r}}\end{eqnarray*}$$
that can be re-written through the [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula), but does not have a "nice" closed form.

Comment: Sorry but I have a small question: why $e^{ikx}= \cos{(kx)}$ ?

Comment: @Nizar: that is obviously not true, but the imaginary part of the integral is the integral of an odd function over a symmetric domain, hence the sine part of $e^{ikx}=\cos(kx)+i\,sin(kx)$ gives no contribute.

Comment: Okay thank you,,I get it now !

Comment: I already did all this and I currently use this sum in computations. It converges quickly. So the answer is apparently that there is no closed form. Thank you for the clarification